# Prove that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sin^3{\frac{2}{n}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sin^3{\frac{2}{n}}$$

The only thing I can think of is that sinus cubed behaves similarly to the $\frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n}$ series, but that really leads me nowhere... I am completely stuck.

How would you go about showing this series converges? Thank you.

Comment: Unless you are adopting the Russian convention $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ the series should start at $n=1$, otherwise the very first term does not make sense. Then it is enough to exploit $0\leq \sin x \leq x$ for any $x\in[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\bigl|\sin x\bigr|\leqslant|x|$, $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\left|\sin^3\frac2n\right|\leqslant\frac8{n^3}$. Now, apply the comparison test.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin(x) \sim x$, as $x \to 0$, so we have that $\sin^3\left( \frac 2n \right) \sim \left( \frac{2}{n} \right)^3$ as $ n \to \infty$ So use the limit comparison test to show that the series converges absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inequalities $0\le\sin x\le x$ for $0\le x\le\pi$ and $0\le{2\over n}\le\pi$ for $n\ge1$ to conclude

$$0\le\sum\sin^3\left(2\over n\right)\le\sum\left(2\over n\right)^3=8\sum{1\over n^3}$$